# Deriving currently on loan items

Tags: sql, linq, database-design, deriving

I have a table of loan information.

example:

```
_________________________________________________________________
|id|LoanDate|EquipmentId|FromUser|FromLocation|ToUser|ToLocation|
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|1 |2012-1-1| 100       | NULL   |  219       | 605  | NULL     |
|2 |2012-1-2| 100       | 605    |  NULL      | NULL | 219      |
|3 |2012-1-3| 100       | NULL   |  219       | 509  | NULL     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, user 605 was loaned equipment for one day, then returned it the following day. Then the equipment was loaned to a different user the day after that.

How would I go about trying to find which user which currently has what piece of equipment currently on loan to them, considering that this table has entries that track the movement - including returns across dates.

Any ideas about how to go about this would be appreciated. Pseudo-code, SQL or LINQ are fine too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you order the loans by LoanDate descending and then group by `EquipmentId`, the first element in each group will be the most recent loan for its `EquipmentId`.  If the `userId` is not null, then that is the ID of the user who currently has the equipment.

```
var items = from loan in loans
            orderby loan.LoanDate desc
            group loan by loan.EquipmentId into grp
            let userId = grp.First().ToUser
            where userId != null
            select new { EquipmentId = grp.Key, UserId = userId };
```